# Classification for 'not something' Neural Networks

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, cnn

This is a very basic question about neural networks in general.

How do you have a classification for 'not something'?

Example: Say that you have to determine the accuracy of a certain simulation by comparing it to the actual scenario (in this case, comparing simulated and actual galaxy images). Theoretically, I can make a CNN and classify these images as 'galaxies' and 'not galaxies'. But what kind of images do I need to use for 'not galaxies'? I only have images for true galaxies.

Comment: in principle you can use any kind(s) of „non galaxy“ image. However, you may have an idea of what the „non galaxy“ class might be (what type of images are most important). You can check false classifications to see what types of „non galaxy“ images are classified as galaxies. You could then try to work out how to distinguish there images from galaxies (e.g. by oversampling).

Comment: @Peter but even the improper simulations have some properties of proper ones. So, by 'any kind of non galaxy image', what exactly do you mean? Sure, I can get a few wrong simulation pictures, but I certainly don't have hundreds of them, which is required for this.

Comment: Ah, okay, you work with a small sample... This is a really big problem, since image classification in NN needs „large“ samples and one shot learning will likely not work because of the complexity of images. Lets see what suggestions come up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem resembles the learning task of 'one-class classification', otherwise known as anomaly detection. Essentially, you have a set of images all belonging to one class (galaxies), and you want a model to tell you if a new image is a galaxy or not, without providing any counter-examples to train with.

You should try a recently developed method called Deep Support Vector Data Description. In this method, a transformation is learned by a neural network to map the inputs to points contained in a small hypersphere in latent space. Then, examples falling inside the hypersphere can be considered 'galaxies', and outside can be considered 'not galaxies'.

You can read more about it [here](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v80/ruff18a.html) (quite technical), or just try to use the authors' PyTorch implementation [here](https://github.com/lukasruff/Deep-SVDD-PyTorch).

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly the thing I required! Can this problem be tackled like other NN methods (like ResNet, VGG, etc.) or is it vastly different?

Comment: Also, another side query. Suppose I have 3 classes of galaxies (spiral, barred, elliptical); how should I incorporate the usual CNN with anomaly detection? My first guess is that there will now be 3 small hyperspheres, and the ones outside will be rejected.

Comment: I would imagine any kind of network will be fine -- simply change the code in `set_network` of `deepSVDD.py` to build your own network. The thing that makes it work is in the loss function, so it should be okay.

Comment: If you have three different classes, I would approach the task a bit differently. I would create a multiclass neural network as usual with three units in the output layer, and use the `sigmoid` nonlinearity rather than `softmax`. This will produce a score between 0 and 1 for each class, but _without_ the caveat that they must sum to one. This way, if all three units give a near-zero (perhaps < 0.1) score, you can say that the image is not of a galaxy; otherwise, predict the class with the highest score.

Comment: I shall try that. Do you know if this github code is available in Tensorflow? I am not familiar with PyTorch

Comment: They have Theano code, which is pretty similar to Tensorflow, here: https://github.com/lukasruff/Deep-SVDD

Comment: I did start working on the PyTorch DeepSVDD code. But I am stuck at the data loading part. My data consists of labelled train images and unlabelled test image. I am not able to find a decent method to load these images in the format required in the code. Do I have to load them through a csv file? Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: @Quasar PyTorch has quite rich data loading functionality. Try looking into `torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder` and `torch.data.DataLoader`.